# using psycopg2 to call postgres function which takes an array of a custom type

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I currently have a custom type in postgres:

```
create type times_type as
(
  start varchar,
  end   varchar,
  rate real
);
```

I also have a function which takes an array of times_type:

```
create function insert_data(times_values times_type[])
```

When I was using named tuples and using callproc to insert one value at a time it worked fine i.e:

```
 Document = namedtuple('times_type', 'start 
                             end rate')


 cur.callproc('insert_data',
                     (Document('13:00', '16:00', 12.56))
```

But now the function is expecting an array, so i attempted:

```
Document = namedtuple('times_type', 'start 
                             end rate')


 cur.callproc('insert_data',
                     ([Document('13:00', '16:00', 12.56),
                       Document('17:00', '18:00', 12.56),
                       Document('19:00', '20:00', 12.56)])
```

psycopg2 gives me an error that the function does not exist. Is there something you have to do when dealing with an array of custom types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with arrays of a composite type is that they have to be explicitly cast, otherwise Postgres see them as `record[]`. Use [`register_adapter(class, adapter)`](http://psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html#sql-adaptation-protocol-objects).

```
Document = namedtuple('times_type', 'start end rate')

class DocumentAdapter:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.adapted = psycopg2.extensions.SQL_IN(x)
    def prepare(self, conn):
        self.adapted.prepare(conn)
    def getquoted(self):
        return self.adapted.getquoted() + b'::times_type'

psycopg2.extensions.register_adapter(Document, DocumentAdapter)

cur.callproc('insert_data',
                     ([Document('13:00', '16:00', 12.56),
                       Document('17:00', '18:00', 12.56),
                       Document('19:00', '20:00', 12.56)],)) # comma added, this should be a tuple
                       
conn.commit();  # dont forget to commit
```